# Comparing pdfs in l3build allays fails for engines other than pdftex

Tags: l3build

I have the following testfile  (`testdefinitioninheritance.lvt`) that generated some output.

```
\input{regression-test}
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{docvar}
\begin{document}
\START


\OMIT
\definedocvar{title}
\setdocvar{title}{Long Title Sentence}
\definedocvar[inherit=title]{subtitle}
\TIMO


\getdocvar{subtitle}

\showoutput
\vfill\break
\END
\end{document}
```

I run the save command

```
texlua build.lua save -p testdefinitioninheritance
```

The saved pdf files look ok visually.

If I run the checks afterwards

```
texlua build.lua check -p testdefinitioninheritance
```

The `pdftex` check passes always, but the `xetex` and `luatex` fails. I found that there is a  file `build/test/testdefinitioninheritance.ref.pdf` that is build with `pdftex`. Shouldn't be a pdf file for each engine?

(Note: running TL2017 with the lastest update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, a head-up: it's likely that the set up here will change somewhat as the team feel that using a switch is likely not the best way to alter test outcomes. This reflects the fact that PDF-based testing is not currently used by the team and that this area is therefore somewhat experimental.

Testing using a binary comparison of PDFs is rather different to comparing different log output as we cannot do any normalisation: either the two results are *identical* or they are not. With different engines, you will get variations between the outcomes partly as they deliberately do different things (*e.g.* the producer string) and partly as they have different code flows (*e.g.* XeTeX goes *via* an `.xdv` file so the PDF creation is very different from that in pdfTeX).

At present, `l3build` uses the same logic for creating reference PDF files as for creating reference `.tlg` files: unless called with the `-e` switch, the reference file is created using the default engine (normally pdfTeX). As such, if you want to do PDF-based comparisons for multiple engines you'll need to save them all separately

```
texlua build.lua save -epdftex,xetex,luatex -p testdefinitioninheritance
```

I think it's worth bearing in mind that the expectation is that PDF-based comparisons are likely most appropriate for situations where there is only one engine to test. For cross-engine work it would normally be the case that one or more `.tlg` files can be created.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My intent is not to cross-check different engines. I was not aware that I can pass a list of engines to `-e`. By the way I tested to build the 3 reference files and the next check (without changes) fail in luatex.

Comment: @TeXtnik I'll look again at LuaTeX: for TL'16 there were some issues with the support for the necessary variables.